# toggle div with a class name derived from a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I am having a JavaScript function where the classname comes as a parameter. So i want to toggle() the specific class name which came in the parameter. How should i do this? I tried like this but it doesnt work.

```
function hideclass(classval){
$("#divname.classval").toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 function hideclass(classval){
    $("#divname."+classval).toggle();
 }
```

or

```
function hideclass(classval){
    $("#divname").hasClass(classval).toggle();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply concatenate the value to the text of the selector:

```
function hideclass(classval){
    $("#divname." + classval).toggle();
}
```